# mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I have changed my database from SQLite to Mongo DB in `setting.py` and I have also run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and everything seems to work fine but after starting the server with `python manage.py runserver` it given me the following error

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 25, 2022 - 18:48:03
Django version 4.0.4, using settings 'passmanager.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 31, in get_handler        
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 78, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 30, in import_string
    return cached_import(module_path, class_name)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 15, in cached_import
    import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "E:\projects\pass-manager\password-manager\app\passmanager\wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 126, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\Ashutosh Anand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 61, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(adapted_handler)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

**Setting.py file**

```
"""
Django settings for passmanager project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
from django.utils.timezone import activate
from django.conf import settings
from pytz import timezone

activate(settings.TIME_ZONE)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'Removed!'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'crispy_forms'
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'passmanager.urls'

# AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'urlcrypt.auth_backends.UrlCryptBackend' )

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'passmanager.wsgi.application'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'uni_form'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

# DATABASES = {
#     'default': {
#         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#         'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
#     }
# }
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': 'PasswordManager',
            'ENFORCE_SCHEMA': False,
            'CLIENT': {
                'host': 'mongodb+srv://loopassembly:<removed!>@cluster0.cwtfb.mongodb.net/test'
            }  
        }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

### Note

> If any of the file are needed pls let me know in a comment thank you

Comment: Why do you have `'django.contrib.admin'`, and the lines after it in the `MIDDLEWARE` list?? Those should be the cause of the error.

Comment: oh man, thx a lot that was the actual issue btw do u know why they were causing the error because I was using it with SQLite they were working fine but when I switched to mongo DB error arises @AbdulAzizBarkat